# Symfony - CSRF not working in some mobile browsers

Tags: php, symfony

I have symfony form that send via ajax and persist/update it on database.

this process work correctly in desktop browsers but on mobile browsers (almost safari and another apple browsers) get error: `This CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form`

- I use `{{ form_end(form) }}` twig (my symfony version is 3.2)
- I increased both `max_input_vars` and `upload_max_filesize` properties of my `php.ini`.
- My database is up to date.
- I cleared my app and browser caches.
- **This Work Correctly In Desktop Browsers**
- **This Error In Apple Browsers**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have cookies enabled on the mobile browsers since the CSRF token is stored in the session and without cookies a session can not be created.

Comment: cookies allowed on that browser.